# Why can not get HTML code of this url?

Tags: php, html, get

I used file_get_contents, curl, simple html dom but can not get HTML from this url:
http://www.zing.vn/news/xa-hoi/choang-voi-clip-cu-ba-cao-tuoi-nhay-boc-nhu-vu-cong/a124040.html

I don't know why, but the result is haphazard characters, not HTML code.

Comment: It would help a lot if you post the first few lines of whatever you got, so that we can get a better understanding of what exactly you mean with "haphazard characters". There are people who understands whatever you don't understand (and that's why you posted the question here, right? :) )

Comment: Looks like regular source to me

Comment: Post at least some of your code. Just saying what functions you used really isn't enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **CURLOPT_ENCODING**, if empty, curl will handle the encoding itself and that's exactly what you need :)

I've tested the code below and it returns the correct character encoding .

```
$url ="http://www.zing.vn/news/xa-hoi/choang-voi-clip-cu-ba-cao-tuoi-nhay-boc-nhu-vu-cong/a124040.html";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,""); 
$pagebody=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $pagebody;
```

Comment: Yeah! With CURLOPT_ENCODING, curl can get HTML code of that url. My problem is resolved! Thanks Tuga so much! Thanks every body has commented to help me!

Answer (score 4):

That webpage seems to always return gzip-encoded content (even if the client doesn't claim to support it). You can decode the gzipped content using [`gzinflate`](http://www.php.net/gzinflate).